# meta mask registers ether delta as a probable phishing site

Tags: etherdelta, phishing

My question is about how recently when I go to ether delta my metamask registers it as a phishing site and does not let me interact with the site? what should I do and what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EtherDelta's DNS server has been hacked today and Metamask has blocked it to prevent people from losing their funds until ED recovers.

EtherDelta's smart contracts are safe (according to what they've said) so it shouldn't pose a risk to funds deposited in there.

Here's more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/7l46ng/alert_ether_delta_hacked/

Comment: Do you have any idea about when ED will be back up?